# Postgresql doesn't working with Citus and pg_stat_statements at the same time

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, postgresql-extensions, citus

So, I built the PostgreSQL with citus extension in docker.
I use the official documentation in citus, then I run this command in the terminal.

```
docker run -d -v /root/volumes/citus-data:/data  --network citus-network --name citus_coordinator -p 5500:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword citusdata/citus:11.1
```

Then Database successfully building.
But I want to create the `pg_stat_statements` extension.
I configuration the  `postgresql.conf` file.

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = all
pg_stat_statements.max = 10000
track_activity_query_size = 2048
```

Then I restarted the PostgreSQL container. Wrote the this query

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_statements;
```

in terminal.
I saw this error

```
[55000] ERROR: pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries
```

I didn't understand, why the config file didn't see this extension, What was my mistake?

**Solved**
I am running the PostgreSQL container with postgres:latest image.
Then  I entered the container.
So, I installed the citus from [here](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.1/installation/single_node_debian.html) into the container.
Then installed `apt-get install postgresql-contrib` into the container.Next step, run `create extension pg_stat_statements;`
And everything worked for me.

Comment: I don't see you defining a persistent volume mapping in your docker command; without persistent storage, whatever you change inside a container will disappear upon restart.

Comment: @mustaccio oh sorry , I editin the post

Comment: @GismatHusein you can put the "solved" part in an answer (and remove it from the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `citus` and `pg_stat_statements` should be present in `shared_preload_libraries`: `shared_preload_libraries = 'citus, pg_stat_statements'`

[Docs](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.1/admin_guide/cluster_management.html?highlight=shared_preload_libraries#postgresql-extensions)

Comment: I have the same issue again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart the Postgresql Server in order to load the shared library

and afterwards execute

CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;

Before you can use it.

Comment: I do it. But I see the same error. ```pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries```